# What does "User-specified initial value defined for instance tp.zf is being ignored" mean from a synthesis tool?

Tags: synthesis

Basically, what does this Synplify output mean:

```
@N: MT206 |Auto Constrain mode is enabled
@W: FX1039 :"c:\sftp_root\x002\tinyproc.v":61:3:61:8|User-specified initial value defined for instance tp.zf is being ignored. 
@W: FX1039 :"c:\sftp_root\x002\tinyproc.v":61:3:61:8|User-specified initial value defined for instance tp.cf is being ignored. 
@W: FX1039 :"c:\sftp_root\x002\tinyproc.v":61:3:61:8|User-specified initial value defined for instance tp.pc[7:0] is being ignored. 
@W: FX1039 :"c:\sftp_root\x002\tinyproc.v":61:3:61:8|User-specified initial value defined for instance tp.intra[1:0] is being ignored. 
@W: FX1039 :"c:\sftp_root\x002\tinyproc.v":61:3:61:8|User-specified initial value defined for instance tp.tv[15:0] is being ignored. 
@W: FX1039 :"c:\sftp_root\x002\tinyproc.v":61:3:61:8|User-specified initial value defined for instance tp.port[3:0] is being ignored. 
@W: FX1039 :"c:\sftp_root\x002\tinyproc.v":61:3:61:8|User-specified initial value defined for instance tp.instr[15:0] is being ignored.
```

Are initial register states not specifiable on FPGAs? I'm targeting iCE40 family (specifically, iCE40HX1K - the "icestick" platform).

Comment: welcome to stack. please detail your question and post a minimal, complete, and verifiable example - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

This warning must mean that your target FPGA does not support initial values for registers. If you have a declaration like below, Synplify will ignore the initial value.

```
reg zf = 1'b0;
```

Synthesis will proceed as if the declaration is like the following.

```
reg zf;
```

The thing you can do is to initialize the registers by a reset signal. If you have already done that, you can ignore the warnings. Still, I would remove the initial values to avoid any potential mismatch between simulation and synthesis.